# Try to run line for a specific time interval

Tags: java, android

So I want to know if there is a way of running a line for a specific time interval in java. I am currently developing an Android application and I am trying to run the same line for a few seconds.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pay careful attention to the notes in the answers, which hint that the way to do literally what you are asking in Java generically can be problematic when applied to Android, which assumes a UI thread reserved for quickly executing event methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check them, and choose which is best for you:

[Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)
[ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

I think `Timer` is better for this case.

---

Timer - Example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        method();
    }
};
// every 3 seconds
timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);
```

---

ScheduledExecutorService - Example from Android doc:

> Here is a class with a method that sets up a ScheduledExecutorService
>   to beep every ten seconds for an hour:

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); 
     };
     final ScheduledFuture beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
 }}
```

All this create a thread so you don't block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
long timestart = System.currentTimeMillis();
int desiredTimeInSecs = 3; 

while (System.currentTimeMillis() < timeStart + desiredTimeInSecs*1000){
     yourCommand();
}
```

i would make it concurrent to not block your UIThread.